# attaching template content from within a polymer element

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am trying to have certain content of a polymer element procedurally added, at a time later than its creation. I am trying to avoid a `<template is="dom-if">` element.

Instead I am trying to have a nested `<template>` element inside the polymer element's template and have its content attached on the execution of a method, like so:

```
<dom-module id="simple-element">

    <template>

        <content id="content"></content>
        <div id="display">display</div>

        <template id="t">
          template content
          <script>console.log("template added!")</script>
        </template>

    </template>

    <script>

    var simpleElement = {

        is: "simple-element",


        attached : function(){
            this.init();
        },

        init : function(){

            var t = document.importNode(this.$.t.content,true);
            this.$.display.appendChild(t);

        },
    }



    Polymer(simpleElement);


    </script>
</dom-module>
```

See it also in this jsbin http://jsbin.com/zudituvuli/edit?html,js,console,output

Is there a way to accomplish this?